# Ng2-Chart - Assign JSON Data To DataSet

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ng2-charts

I have the below JSON data and these are attendance details for the few last days:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2021-09-07T00:00:00",
        "type": "Teacher",
        "total": 744
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-07T00:00:00",
        "type": "Student",
        "total": 4769
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-08T00:00:00",
        "type": "Teacher",
        "total": 740
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-08T00:00:00",
        "type": "Student",
        "total": 4743
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-09T00:00:00",
        "type": "Teacher",
        "total": 736
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-09T00:00:00",
        "type": "Student",
        "total": 4714
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-10T00:00:00",
        "type": "Teacher",
        "total": 52
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-10T00:00:00",
        "type": "Student",
        "total": 47
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-11T00:00:00",
        "type": "Teacher",
        "total": 648
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-11T00:00:00",
        "type": "Student",
        "total": 4341
    }
]
```

I am using a template for test purposes and this is the link for it, it uses ng2-chart:

[Purple Angular](https://bootstrapdash.com/demo/purple-angular-free/preview/dashboard)

**GitHub Link**: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/BootstrapDash/PurpleAdmin-Free-Admin-Template)

I tried to assign those JSON data into a dataset and tried to use the ng2-chart from the template:

[image: Chart]

My plan is to show the last 4/6 days' attendance data (JSON data) in the chart as dates in the horizontal line and in the vertical line, it'll have the teacher/student total attendance for specific dates. I analyzed the chart already and tried something as follows:

```js
//Get Last Four Days Data
LoadLastFour() {
  debugger;
  this.dataservice.GetLastFour().subscribe(result => {
    this.lastFour = JSON.parse(result);

    this.visitSaleChartData = [{
      label: this.lastFour.map((m: any) => m.type),
      data: this.lastFour.map((m: any) => m.total),
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false,
    }];

    this.visitSaleChartLabels = [this.lastFour.map((m: any) => m.date)]

    console.log(this.lastFour);
  }, error => console.error(error)); 
}
```

In the template, it has data source as follows:

```
<canvas baseChart #visitSaleChart 
    [chartType]="'bar'" *ngIf="visitSaleChartData" 
    [datasets]="visitSaleChartData" [labels]="visitSaleChartLabels" 
    [options]="visitSaleChartOptions" [colors]="visitSaleChartColors"></canvas>
```

```js
visitSaleChartData = [{
  label: 'CHN',
  data: [20, 40, 15, 35, 25, 50, 30, 20],
  borderWidth: 1,
  fill: false,
},
{
  label: 'USA',
  data: [40, 30, 20, 10, 50, 15, 35, 40],
  borderWidth: 1,
  fill: false,
},
{
  label: 'UK',
  data: [70, 10, 30, 40, 25, 50, 15, 30],
  borderWidth: 1,
  fill: false,
}];

visitSaleChartLabels = ["2013", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"];
```

The issue is when I render the chart in the front-end, it shows only a bar and under it, all the dates are aligned row by row though it should create the dates horizontally side by side.

Any way that I can make it work or require anything specific?

**Working Sample**: [Stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-qzd9ff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concept

1. Group `lastFour` data by `type` (Student/Teacher).
2. Remove key from `groupedByTypeResult` (Step 1) to append to `chartData` and for `visitSaleChartData`.
3. Format date with `DatePipe` and Distinct date (remove duplicates) for `visitSaleChartLabels`.

---

### Solution

> app.component.html

```
<div style="display: block;">
  <canvas baseChart #visitSaleChart 
    [chartType]="'bar'" 
    *ngIf="visitSaleChartData" 
    [datasets]="visitSaleChartData" 
    [labels]="visitSaleChartLabels" 
    [options]="visitSaleChartOptions" 
    [colors]="visitSaleChartColors" 
    ></canvas>
</div>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {

  lastFour: any[] = [];
  visitSaleChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];
  visitSaleChartLabels = [];
  visitSaleChartOptions = {};
  visitSaleChartColors = [];

  constructor(private dataservice: DataService, private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.LoadLastFour();
  }

  LoadLastFour() {
    this.dataservice.GetLastFour().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.lastFour = result;

        // Group Last Four by Type
        let groupedByTypeResult: any[] = this.lastFour.reduce(function(
          obj: any,
          item: any
        ) {
          let type = item.type;

          obj[type] = obj[type] || { label: item.type, data: [] };
          obj[type].data.push(item.total);

          return obj;
        },
        {});

        // Remove key to append to chartData
        let chartData = [];
        for (let type in groupedByTypeResult) {
          chartData.push({
            label: groupedByTypeResult[type].label,
            data: groupedByTypeResult[type].data,
            borderWidth: 1,
            fill: false
          });
        }

        this.visitSaleChartData = chartData;

        // Distinct date for chartLabel
        this.visitSaleChartLabels = [
          ...new Map(
            this.lastFour.map(item => [
              item.date,
              this.datePipe.transform(item.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
            ])
          ).values()
        ];
      },
      error => console.error(error)
    );
  }
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-39ztva)

> Output

[image]

Comment: Looks promising @Yong Shun. Will check it and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same things, but I don't want to group Last Four by Type how I can change this block.

```
 let groupedByTypeResult: any[] = this.lastFour.reduce(function(
      obj: any,
      item: any
    ) {
      let type = item.type;

      obj[type] = obj[type] || { label: item.type, data: [] };
      obj[type].data.push(item.total);

      return obj;
    },
    {});
```